# Installing forexconnect

Tags: pip

```
PS C:\Users\Gabriel Johnson\Documents\FXCM> pip install forexconnect
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement forexconnect (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for forexconnect

PS C:\Users\Gabriel Johnson\Documents\FXCM> pip install forexconnect
```